# What is the mechanism by which seeds stay alive while in storage?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I know folks who store seeds for months and sometimes a year before planting them. What is the mechanism by which they stay alive?

Also some associated questions:

How do the cells in the seed stay alive without resources for so long?

How long can the seeds stay alive in storage?

Does storing them long affect their growth?

Comment: What resources have you checked on [seed dormancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed_dormancy)? You’ll likely have to narrow the scope of your question for it to receive a good answer.

Comment: I suggest a little preliminary research.  But a year is really nothing for seeds: there's a date palm in Israel that was grown from a 2000 year old seed.  With a little assistance, plants were grown from 31,000 year old Silene stenophylla seeds.  It's also perfectly normal for seeds in the environment to grow after many years, wen conditions are right, e.g. a rainstorm for desert ephemerals, a fire for seeds that require smoke exposure to germinate, or just being exposed to light when I till my garden :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeds are made from cells in an amorphous metastable superviscous state because the cell's cytoplasm becomes a solid matrix of hydrogenated oil and sugar. The fats also contain a lot of anti-oxidants, so that ambient oxygen that can affect the dormant cells is absorbed by buffer chemicals.

The sugars and oils in the cell cytoplasm (the inside of the cell) become [hydrogenated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_hydrogenation), and change into margarine and then become solidified fat and solidified sugar. Then the consistency of the cell at that stage becomes glassy because it's so solid, which is what you can see if you try to crack a peanut or a lentil, it has a glassy surface. The cell fats can rapidly become liquid again if they absorb water and change their chemistry.
[references and images](https://www.google.com/search?q=glass%20seed%20cytoplasm&sxsrf=ALeKk01vAAbUHHhvimITPT2bvUIyq-2fuQ:1616552136935&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq2Yf_7cfvAhVBZhQKHaMVARYQ_AUoAXoECAQQAw&biw=1267&bih=711#imgrc=gbrxYWt9rNi2fM)
It's not very different from microbe dormancy, so it's like an ancient biological trick that cells have been doing for billions of years.

The cotyledon is the future baby leaves of the seedling, the radicle is the root and the plumule is the leaf shoots, they are all made of cells that are in a solidified dehydrated form made of fats and sugars and special chemicals that resist ambient water and oxygenation in a controlled way.[image]